# More than one between clause

Tags: mysql, between

How can I use more than one 'between' clause in a MySQL query? For example if I want to select students having height between 20 and 25 and weight between 50 and 70.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE height BETWEEN 20 AND 25 AND weight BETWEEN 50 AND 70
```

Comment: maybe you should use the and operator

Comment: Should be `... AND weight BETWEEN 50 AND 70`

Comment: No it shouldn't. How can a value be between 20 and 25, and 50 and 70 at the same time? If my height is 23, it can't be 62 at the same time.

Comment: Oops, I misread the question. I thought he wanted height for both, but I see that he wanted weight for the second criteria now. Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE height BETWEEN 20 AND 25 AND weight BETWEEN 50 AND 70`

Bear in mind that your condition being applied to each row one-by-one, not to "whole table at once".